# VBA, importing large data from multiple workbooks into mastersheet

Tags: vba, excel

My code currently opens a file picker and selects files and a particular column im interested in combining into my master worksheet.

I pick several .csv files and bring in a column of my choosing .

Issue I have are,

1) these files are large, 400kb.

2) I get run time error 1004, copy area and paste area are not the same size and shape. Am I just running out of space on my excel sheet? when i debug i get error on line `copyRng.Copy destRng`

My end goal is to see and count and see the unique values from Col C(perhaps some other columns) from all my workbooks.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsMaster As Workbook, csvFiles As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim File As Integer
Dim r As Long

Public Sub Consolidate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select files to process"
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook

Dim copyRng As Range, destRng As Range
Dim firstRow As Long
For File = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

    Filename = .SelectedItems.Item(File)

    If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
        Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
        r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '' This is the main new part
        Set copyRng = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & r)
        With wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1")
            firstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            Set destRng = .Range("A" & firstRow + 1).Offset(0, 1)
        End With

        copyRng.Copy destRng
        ''''''''''
        csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False    'close without saving
    End If
Next File

    End With

    Set wsMaster = Nothing
    Set csvFiles = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Updated code with below recommendation

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsMaster As Workbook, csvFiles As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim File As Integer
Dim r As Long

Public Sub Consolidate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select files to process"
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook

Dim copyRng As Range, destRng As Range
Dim firstRow As Long
For File = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

    Filename = .SelectedItems.Item(File)




    If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
    Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
    r = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '' This is the main new part
    Set copyRng = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & r)
    With wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1")
        firstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set destRng = .Range("B" & firstRow & "B" & (firstRow + r))
    End With

    destRng.Value = copyRng.Value
    ''''''''''
    csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False    'close without saving
End If


Next File

    End With

    Set wsMaster = Nothing
    Set csvFiles = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When defining `copyRng` why start at the bottom row? Normally one would use `Set copyRng = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & r)`. Also, as you are pasting across rather than down, you should be checking the first column rather than row not used (I think).

Comment: @SJR, thanks for the check, absolutely right, I meant to do C1:C.

Comment: OK, but now I notice that `r` relates to a different sheet?

Comment: @SJR, im confused. I think this is just a mess at this point, i tried to change it back to C1:C . and only get the headers of my files. i forget why I changed it to that

Comment: The problem might be that you are checking the last row in column C of sheet1 of wsmaster, and then using that as the basis of how many rows to copy from sheet1 of csvfiles. That doesn't seem to be logical to me (but then I don't know what you are doing).

Comment: As SJR said. You're currently getting the `rows.count` from a different sheet. `r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. While you should get the `rows.count` of the workbook you've just opened.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of rows is defined by `r` you can set the dimensions of the destination range. The change below should fix the copy-paste error and speed up your code by eliminating use of the clipboard (assuming you only want the values to be copied).

```
If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
    Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
    r = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '' This is the main new part
    Set copyRng = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("C1:C" & r)
    With wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1")
        firstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set destRng = .Range("B" & firstRow & ":B" & (firstrow + r))
    End With

    DestRng.value = CopyRng.value
    ''''''''''
    csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False    'close without saving
End If
```

Comment: I get a debug error on `Set destRng = .Range("B" & firstRow & "B" & (firstRow + r))`

Comment: Have just edited - might just have been a missing colon.

Comment: weirdly enough it is giving me the column header twice, in my master, b2 and b3

Comment: @excelguy If the column header is always the same you could just leave it in there, and adjust the ranges to leave out the column header when copying.

Comment: @excelguy Yes try that. Let me know if it works that way.

Comment: @Slaqr , when i do it to one file its giving me the header only, with C1:C .  The header twice. Would you be able to clean up my whole code? I feel like it is messing up somewhere.

Comment: @excelguy Can you tell me if the "C" column is always filled? And what value does `r` give? It seems like `r` isn't giving the correct last row.

Comment: @Slaqr , yes C is always filled, When stepping through the code,  r seems to give the value of the row count of the file or last file i am opening. I notice it goes back to the top of code a few after i choose my file and i have to choose it 3 times. not sure why.

Comment: Strange. Do you know at which line it went back to the top?

Comment: @Slaqr , I am still getting errors on my original code, sigh, sometimes I will get a debug error if I use too many files. Error here, `    Set destRng = .Range("B" & firstRow & "B" & (firstRow + r))`

Comment: @excelguy Hmm, can you check the values of `firstrow` and `r` at the moment of the error?

Comment: @Slaqr  , first row = 2, r = 17, seems to be the 2nd row to the last row of the file selected.  currently my range is `Set copyRng = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D" & r)`  and my first row is `firstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: @excelguy I can't really see a reason why it would give an error based on those values. Did you check if the problem might lie in the sheet?